# Browse function in python

Tags: python, wxpython

I've implemented a browse button in my program. Now, I'm wondering how i can take that file the user browsed for, and gain it's location/"file path" on the user's system.

So basically, the user browses for an image file, and then i want to move that image to a new folder in the program's directory, called "import".  I plan to do so using command prompt, with a copy command. I just don't know how to code the event for the browse button. can you guys give me a simple code to use for this scenario?

Comment: Which GUI framework are you using? For example, Qt have an easy-to-use QFileBrowser class.

Comment: I am currently using wxpython. Is there like a GUI for creating GUI's?? lol.

Comment: @uer715578: sure there is - google for "wxglade"

Comment: http://www.oneminutepython.com/

Answer (score 4):

In a wxPython `wxFrame`:

```
dialog = wx.FileDialog(
    self, "Choose some files...", self._defaultDirectory, "",
    "BMP files (*.bmp)|*.bmp|GIF files (*.gif)|*.gif", wx.FD_OPEN|wx.FD_MULTIPLE)
if dialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
    paths = dialog.GetPaths()
dialog.Destroy()
```

Comment: Thanks for that snippet erbridge!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code for saving:

```
saveFileDialog = wx.FileDialog(self, "Save Report", "", "", ".csv files (*.csv)|*.csv", wx.FD_SAVE | wx.FD_OVERWRITE_PROMPT)
if saveFileDialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_CANCEL:
        return     # the user has cancelled
print saveFileDialog.GetPath()
```